# Failed to parse ZooKeeper status for the node at path

Tags: 18.04

I'm upgrading tableau server from 10.5.2 to 10.5.9 following the instructions [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/sug_upgrade_10_5.htm)

I downloaded the installation file and then did:

```
sudo gdebi -n tableau-server-10-5-9_amd64.deb

sudo /opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/scripts.10500.18.1008.1759/upgrade-tsm --accepteula
```

This gives:

> ERROR: Upgrade failed with exit code 60. See log file at
>   /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/logs/app-upgrade.log for details.

The log says:

```
2018-11-04 14:43:27.509 +0000 Curator-TreeCache-2 : ERROR com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.impl.ServiceStatusWatcher - Failed to parse ZooKeeper status for the node at path /tableau/tabsvc-clusterid/stat$
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: [B@7aaabe71; line: 1, column: 0]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:216)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3833)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3774)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2872)
        at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.impl.ServiceStatusWatcher.nodeUpdated(ServiceStatusWatcher.java:135)
```

I can't find any info on this error with google nor in tableau website.
Anyone knows how to solve this?